Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Repositories what is the difference between noble vs noble-updates vs noble-security vs noble-backports
What is the difference between noble vs noble-updates vs noble-security vs noble-backports?
Which one is mandatory and stable?
Can anyone share the related documents if available?

@ArturMeinild you persuaded me to write an answer. You're an influencer.

@user535733 Upvoted!

noble [Mandatory] - The base package set for the release. These do not get upgraded. Upgraded packages come through the noble-updates and noble-security repos. Many packages receive zero upgrades during the life cycle of a release, so they will be found only here.
noble-security [Mandatory] - Upgraded packages that include patches by the Ubuntu Security Team. Usually only in the main pocket, though Pro customers also get limited universe coverage. Each patch is usually traceable to a specific CVE. No bugfixes. These are almost never new upstream releases. The Ubuntu Security Team strives to keep changes minimal to avoid introducing new bugs.
noble-updates [Mandatory] - In main, these are non-security upgrades (bugfixes). In universe and multiverse, in addition to bugfixes, these upgrades might include community-provided security upgrades that did not run through the Ubuntu Security Team. There are rarely new upstream releases.
noble-backports [Optional] - Upgraded packages that are backported from a newer release of Ubuntu. Sometimes includes new upstream releases. These undergo limited community testing, so not recommended for mission-critical use.
